# Typescript: How to properly combine different types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am currently building a React application with Typescript.

I have a component which makes a call to grab user data from the server (using firebase in my case),
then stores that data inside component state.

```
// Defining my own custom user type
// I tried to "combine" the two types here
type Partial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
};
type MyUserType = Partial<firebase.User> & { myCustomProperty?: string};

// Defining types for component Props and State
type Props = {
  gotUser: boolean;
  userData: firebase.User;
};
type State = {
  currentUser: MyUserType | null;
};

// My component that gets user data and stores it on local state
class App extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      currentUser: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getUserData(); // makes server call to fetch user data
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { gotUser, userData } = this.props;
    if (gotUser) {
      // got user; now save it in component state
      this.setState({
        currentUser: {
          ...userData ,                // spread all of <firebase.User> properties
          myCustomProperty: 'hello',   // ...and also append my own property
        },
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Thank you for any help!</div>
  }
}
```

I had difficulty defining the type for my `this.state.currentUser`.

What I wanted to do was take the object that gets fetched from firebase (which is of type `<firebase.User>`), then combine it with any other properties that I define, ending up with my own custom `MyUserType` type.

I first tried to do

```
type MyUserType = firebase.User & { myCustomProperty?: string; }
```

But the compiler gave me a cryptic error until I used a mapped type like this:

```
type Partial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
};
type MyUserType = Partial<firebase.User> & { myCustomProperty?: string};
```

Did I do this right? Or is there a better way to achieve the same result?

I am very new to Typescript, but I feel like that this problem (taking an existing type and customizing it) is a very common one, and that I solved it in a weird way.

Comment: Partial is already a built-in, so you don't need that. What is the cryptic error you got? It might help

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the interface instead

```js
interface MyUserType extends firebase.User {
  myCustomProperty?: string;
}
```